# Why is my SQL database failing to store a string?

Tags: android, sql, string

I have stored an image path in the string selectedImagePath. Now I want to store this string in a SQL Database. Therefore I have created another class, the ImageAdapter.

Can you please look at the code and tell me why the code always crashes when I try to save the string?

This is my onActivityResult method were I were I retrieve the image path and store it in the string selectedImagePath:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_FILE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

            Log.v("IMAGE PATH====>>>> ",selectedImagePath);

            // Save the image path to the database
            long id = mImageHelper.createImage(selectedImagePath);
            if (id > 0) {
                id = mImageRowId;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my Database helper, the ImageAdapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter {

//
// Database Related Constants
//
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dataImage";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "remindersImage";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;

public static final String KEY_IMAGE = "image";
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";


private static final String TAG = "ImageAdapter";
private DatabaseHelper mImageHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mImageDb;

/**
 * Database creation SQL statement
 */
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ("
            + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + KEY_IMAGE + " text not null)"; 



private final Context mImageCtx;

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

/**
 * Constructor - takes the context to allow the database to be
 * opened/created
 * 
 * @param ctx the Context within which to work
 */
public ImageAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.mImageCtx = ctx;
}

/**
 * Open the database. If it cannot be opened, try to create a new
 * instance of the database. If it cannot be created, throw an exception to
 * signal the failure
 * 
 * @return this (self reference, allowing this to be chained in an
 *         initialization call)
 * @throws SQLException if the database could be neither opened or created
 */
public ImageAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    mImageHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mImageCtx);
    mImageDb = mImageHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    mImageHelper.close();
}



public long createImage(String selectedImagePath) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_IMAGE, selectedImagePath);

    return mImageDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}


public boolean deleteImage(long rowId) {

    return mImageDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}


public Cursor fetchAllImages() {

    return mImageDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_IMAGE}, null, null, null, null, null);
}


public Cursor fetchImage(long rowId) throws SQLException {

    Cursor mCursor =

            mImageDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                    KEY_IMAGE}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
                    null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;

}


public boolean updateImage(long rowId, String image) {
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);

    return mImageDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
}
```

UPDATE: Here is my LogCat:

```
05-31 21:10:14.947: E/AndroidRuntime(533): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-31 21:10:14.947: E/AndroidRuntime(533): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/22 }} to activity {com.xyz.android.taskreminder/com.xyz.android.taskreminder.ReminderEditActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-31 21:10:14.947: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2980)
05-31 21:10:14.947: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3023)
05-31 21:10:14.947: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-31 21:10:14.947: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1177)
05-31 21:10:14.947: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-31 21:10:14.947: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-31 21:10:14.947: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-31 21:10:14.947: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-31 21:10:14.947: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-31 21:10:14.947: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-31 21:10:14.947: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-31 21:10:14.947: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-31 21:10:14.947: E/AndroidRuntime(533): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-31 21:10:14.947: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.releaseAndUnlock(SQLiteStatement.java:290)
05-31 21:10:14.947: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:115)
05-31 21:10:14.947: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1718)
05-31 21:10:14.947: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1591)
05-31 21:10:14.947: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at com.xyz.android.taskreminder.ImageAdapter.createImage(ImageAdapter.java:114)
05-31 21:10:14.947: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at com.xyz.android.taskreminder.ReminderEditActivity.onActivityResult(ReminderEditActivity.java:233)
05-31 21:10:14.947: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4649)
05-31 21:10:14.947: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2976)
05-31 21:10:14.947: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: It would be helpful you would post your stacktrace from LogCat.

Comment: The line `id = mImageRowId` in `onActivityResult` doesn't make any sense. `id` is a local variable that is about to go out of scope. Setting it has no effect. Did you mean to save `id` into `mImageRowId` instead?

Comment: You're certain `selectedImagePath` is not `null`, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, lets clean up some code :)

Change this

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
"create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ("
        + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + KEY_IMAGE + " text not null)";
```

to

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
"create table if not exists " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ("
        + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + KEY_IMAGE + " text not null)";
```

Now, uninstall the app or clear data, so that any previously created databases gets deleted. Try your app, and post results. Please also post the result from this line:

```
Log.v("IMAGE PATH====>>>> ", selectedImagePath);
```

Comment: I changed everything you told me but the app still crashes. And, I am not kidding, the Log.v("IMAGE PATH====>>>> ",selectedImagePath); was not it the LogCat.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any filters on, excluding the verbose version of Log? I can only see one possible option now, and that is that selectedImagePath is null.

Comment: Ah, ok i found it: 05-31 22:12:42.316: V/IMAGE PATH====>>>>(545): /mnt/sdcard/Mercedes_SLS_AMG.jpg

Comment: Ok, so selectedImagePath is not null! This is so strange.. Did you do a full uninstall of the app?

Comment: Ok, i did one more full reinstall of the app and the app crashed again. But, in the LogCat i saw that there was a runtime error at line 236, that means this line in the onActivityresult method: "id = mImageRowId;"

Comment: Finally! Change it to mImageRowId = id;

Answer (score 0):

Do you call `ImageAdapter.open()` before inserting? If not then your `mImageDb` will be `null` and that will cause crash.

Comment: In my onResume method I called mImageHelper.open(). Is that enough or do I have to call it again?

Comment: mImageHelper.open() in onResume() should be enough. Could you please post LogCat?

Comment: Hmm.. Maybe onActivtyResult() is called by the system before onResume()? Try mImageHelper.open() right before mImageHelper.create()!

Comment: It isn't possible for `mImageDb` to be `null`. The stack trace shows that `mImageDb.insert` was called, which would not have been possible if it had been null.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
Ole appropriately pointed out that I assumed you were storing the image, but instead you're storing the **image path** so now I would suggest to follow Ole's answer.

To go a step further on why I suggest that, here's the following:
"It is usually an error to attempt to create a new table in a database that already contains a table, index or view of the same name. However, if the "IF NOT EXISTS" clause is specified as part of the CREATE TABLE statement and a table or view of the same name already exists, the CREATE TABLE command simply has no effect (and no error message is returned). An error is still returned if the table cannot be created because of an existing index, even if the "IF NOT EXISTS" clause is specified."
Source: [sqlite.org](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html)

Also, I always recommend to use `try`-`catch` blocks and `logs` as much as possible in troubleshooting.

Comment: @Ole My mistake, I am currently working on an app that inserts images to sqlite and I guess I read what I wanted and was to quick to jump to answer. Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem :) I just had to edit my answer for the same reason.